# Converting median absolute deviation to standard deviation

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, median, mad

I'm working on some medical research and I'm wondering what is the most straightforward method to convert median and median absolute deviation (MAD) to mean and standard deviation.

If anyone has any links as well to a source I can cite for the conversion that would be super helpful.

The reason I need to convert is because I am doing a meta-analysis based on other studies using RevMan and some studies have mean and SD while others have median and MAD and I want to be able to include them all in one statistical analysis.

I have seen some things about if the data is normally distributed or not, unfortunately, I don't have the original data since I'm doing a meta-analysis of other studies so I don't know if I can just make the assumption that it is normally distributed?

Comment: On its own, can't be done.

Comment: Such a conversion requires different formulae for different distributions, eg, the normal distribution, the logistic distribution, etc. The MAD has some similar properties for symmetric distributions.  The median and the MAD can be better measures than the mean and SD for skewed distributions and skewed data, eg, laboratory measurements of blood components. Why make the conversion? Why not just compute the mean and SD from your data?

Comment: Thanks for adding the reasons why you seek to do this. It would help if you could edit the question further by giving examples of the types of values that you seek to compare/combine across studies. Some types of study outcomes are normal or asymptotically so. There might be information available about typical distributions of other types of outcomes. Also, for those not familiar with Cochrane, please include a web link to RevMan.

Comment: @Yomna Were you to assume symmetry (absent a more specific model) and the median were available you could estimate the mean by the median. If you assume normality then in sufficiently large samples the mean (absolute) deviation from the mean is about $0.798\,σ$ and the median absolute deviation from the median is about $0.6745\,σ$ -- but the samples would need to be quite large for that to be a very good way to either estimate $σ$ or to approximate the sample standard deviation ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... e.g.  under exact normality, at  $n=75$ the ratio of MAD/0.6745 to either $σ$ or $s$ can easily be off by more than $20\%$, and at $n=300$, still by more than $10\%$. Further that ratio can be very sensitive to the tails; if the normal assumption is not correct just  in the far tail, it may be pretty biased.

Comment: The answers sought (as above) depend on the shape of the distribution of data. To use that fact, the distribution shape needs to be characterized, either by theoretical considerations or from shared empirical distribution shapes and a simulation study.

Comment: Adding to the other comments, it's especially perilous here because, usually MAD is used because the distribution of the variable is weird in some way.  Also, the distribution might not follow *any* standard distribution.